# How to extract text from specific rows based on column in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have below csv file reading as df in pands

```
table       entity_name  node_name  src_name      table_col_name    look_up_indicator   type       keys
gw_policy   account       ns0       fullname      insured_name        N                 attribute   NA
gw_policy   polocy        ns1       agent_name    agent               N                 attribute   NA
gw_policy   account       ns2       phone_num     agent_phone         N                 attribute   NA
```

i reading the csv in to pandas and extracting the specific column value

Here in the case i extracting only 'agent' rows from 'table_col_name'

```
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
policy=data.loc[data['table_col_name']=='agent']
print(policy)
```

So here in the case, it will print all the rows fields of policy

```
#Out put
gw_policy   polocy        ns1       agent_name    agent               N                 attribute   NA
```

Now i want to extracts only below rows

```
'ns1' 
'agent_name'
```

so how it is possible with Pandas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```py
policy = data.loc[data['table_col_name']=='agent']
```

to

```py
policy = data.loc[data['table_col_name']=='agent', ['node_name', 'src_name']]
```

The pandas documentation explains how you can index your dataframes:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label

Comment: Thanks @Bob.. this got worked.. by the way can we replace the 'agent' with iteratble value if  we loop
For eg: list_value=['agent','name','afddres']
for i in list_value:
       policy = data.loc[data['table_col_name']==i, ['node_name', 'src_name']]

i tried the way, but iam getting attribute error 'str object has no attribute loc'

Answer (score 1):

You can add list of columns names for [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
policy=data.loc[data['table_col_name']=='agent', ['node_name', 'src_name']]
print(policy)
```